# How do I write a query using the VersionOne API to return all the hours (actuals) recorded under an Epic?

Tags: api, versionone

I need to write a query using the VerisonOne API to return all the time (effort) recorded against tasks under a specific Epic.  My goal is to have the query be a one line statement I can enter into the address bar of my browser.

I've tried the following using the rest-1.v1 query:

http://<>/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic?sel=Epic.ID.Number,SubsAndDown:PrimaryWorkitem[AssetState=%27Closed%27].Actuals.Value.@Sum&where=Epic.ID.Number=%27E-06593%27

http://<>/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Story.ID.Number,Story.Name,SuperAndUp.Number,SuperAndUp.Actuals.@Sum&where=Story.SuperAndUp.ID.Number=%27E-06593%27

Below is the output from the first query above. (similar results from the second query)

Assets total="1" pageSize="2147483647" pageStart="0"
Asset href="/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic/1481442" id="Epic:1481442"
Attribute name="SubsAndDown:PrimaryWorkitem[AssetState='Closed'].Actuals.Value.@Sum"/
/Asset
/Assets

Actual results were no hours returned.  I expected to have ~4,320 hours returned (the total under the Epic E-06593) after the ...@Sum"/

Answer (score 0):

On your first query

```
http://<>/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic?sel=Epic.ID.Number,SubsAndDown:PrimaryWorkitem[AssetState=%27Closed%27].Actuals.Value.@Sum&where=Epic.ID.Number=%27E-06593%27,
```

If you change to AssetState!=Closed then you will get results.  Beware there could be another AssetState that might mess with your total hours. 
You might want filter down to AssetState= "64" or "Active".

See here for https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Getting_Started/Platform_Concepts/Asset_State

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried replacing 'AssetState=Closed' with 'AssetState!=Closed', but it still did not return any effort hours after the ...@Sum"/.  Does the API not return effort hours if the asset is closed? (that would be problematic for us as it would require re-opening numerous assets every time we need to report on historical data).

Comment: To add context:  The portfolio item we are trying to aggregate the effort hours under is in a closed project folder.  And the child stories/tasks under this portfolio item are located in a Sub (child) folder under the folder that the portfolio item is located in.  And effort was recorded throughout story movement between those two folders.

Do we need to specify the folders to include in the query, or would the API understand the Hierarchy and correctly aggregate at the task level from specifying just the top parent Portfolio Item?  Thank you again.